# How do I suppress Lint messages in regards to anonymous structs?

Tags: c, lint, pc-lint

I am running PC-Lint 8.00x on code similar to the following:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int blue  : 5;
        unsigned int green : 6;
        unsigned int red   : 5;
    };
    unsigned short color_value;
} Color_Type;

Color_Type my_color;
unsigned char blue;

blue = (unsigned char)my_color.blue;  /* Lint messages occur here */
```

PC-Lint returns the following error messages:

`Error 40: Undeclared identifier 'blue'`

`Error 63: Expected an lvalue`

The code compiles and runs as expected.  **I am assuming this is because of the anonymous struct, is that assumption correct?  If so, how can I suppress these messages for this particular circumstance?**  I currently suppress messages in the "options.lnt" file as our local coding practice prohibits putting comments directly in the code to suppress Lint messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was posting this I recalled that once upon a time I had set the `+fan` flag and thought that should have covered this case.  I decided to take another look at the PC Lint documentation and quickly discovered that flag only suppresses warning regarding anonymous unions.

I needed to set the `+fas` flag in my "options.lnt" file as well.

After running PC Lint again, all of the warnings I was concerned about were suppressed.  The warnings were, in fact, due to the anonymous struct.